# Combine and Cleanse Multi Row Description in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Input:

[image: Input]

Desired Result:

[image: Desired Result]

I am trying to format an excel file so that it removes the "Item", which is erroneously listed as the first row in the "Description" column, and then combine the remaining multi-row descriptions into a single cell for each unique entry.

What might be the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: "*What might be the best way to accomplish this?*"  I would suggest using VBA or Power Query.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in I2, and drag downwards.. :

```
=IF(B2=A2,IF(LEN(I3)=0,"",I3),B2&IF(A3=""," "&I3,""))
```

Idea :
multiple if condition to 'drag' up the Line1/2/3. use filter to remove unwanted line.. then copy and paste (the filtered table) to another place (values only).